# Solve the following system of equations: $|x-y|=x+y-2$ and $|x+y|=x+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Solve the following system of equations:
>
> $|x-y|=x+y-2$ and $|x+y|=x+2$

I actually don't know how to proceed with this question.

I tried solving both the equations individually, the first one gave me $x=y=1$ while the second one gave me $x=y=2$ but the solutions aren't matching. When I tried $1$ in the $2^{nd}$ equation, it didn't work, similarly, when I tried $2$ in the $1^{st}$ equation, it didn't work.

Please help me with this problem, Thanks!

---

*P.S.: Looking for a graphical approach.*

Comment: My inelegant (slow, pedantic but industrial strength) approach is to divide the constraints into 4 cases depending on whether $(x-y)$ is non-negative or not, and whether $(x+y)$ is non-negative or not.  Then, I attack each case separately, rejecting, within a specific case, any solutions that violate the specific constraints of that case.  For example, under the case that $0 \leq (x+y)$ and $0 \leq (x - y)$ a solution such as $(x = 5, y = 6)$ would have to be rejected as violating the constraints of that particular case.

Comment: Oh no too much work :(
Its a contest question... I doubt the examiners want the students to consume so much time on one question. Thanks though.

Comment: If mathSE was unavailable, and you had never encountered this question before, and you knew that you could resolve it with my method in under 15 minutes, and you were *on your own*, how much time would you invest in *elegance*?

Comment: These graphs look really neat in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sjtuuc7gvv Maybe this can inspire a graphical approach?

Comment: I added a small supplement for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Your expression is **exactly equivalent** to:

$$\begin{cases} (x-y)^2+(x+y)^2 =(x+y-2)^2+(x-2)^2 \\ (x+y)^2-(x-y)^2 =(x+2)^2-(x+y-2)^2  \\ x+2≥0 \\ x+y≥2 \end{cases}$$

Then, we don't have a absolute sign.

---

**Small Supplement**

The above method is the general method we can apply to such equations.  I mean, this method is never bad for you to know.  Because, the following case might not always be valid for different types of questions.

Of course, the easiest and fastest way is this:

$$\begin{align}x+y-2≥0  &\implies  |x+y|=x+y=x+2 \\
&\implies y=2 \end{align}$$

$$|x-2| =x$$

After squaring with $x≥0$,

$$-4x+4=0, x≥0$$

$$x=1.$$

Comment: Where did you get $|x-2|=x$ from? (Sorry if this question is silly)

Comment: @Crease no, it is OK. Putting $y=2$ ,in your first equation. Then you get $$x^2-4x+4=x^2$$

Comment: Oh right. thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you still have questions, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Square both the the equations and choose the values that verify the given equations

Adding a graphical approach soon..

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't even need to square it, from the first equation you get $x+y\ge2$, therefore removing absolute value sign in second equation you get $y=2$. Putting that in first equation you get $|x-2|=x$, hence $x=1$. This is the solution.